# An inequality of the largest eigenvalue of a summation of two matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\lambda_{\text{max}}(A+B)\leq\lambda_{\text{max}}(A)+\|B\|$ where $\|B\|$ denotes the spectral norm of $B$.

Why this is true and any source for this statement?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where did you find this statement? Was there any context?

Comment: @RaadShaikh It is on the last paragraph on the page 6 of the paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.03987.pdf), where $L_{-W}$ is defined as $D_{-W}-(-W)$. The definition of $L$ and $D$ is shown in definition 1.1 on page 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure of this but hopefully it points you in the right direction maybe?

Let $v$ be the unit eigenvector of $A+B$ having largest eigenvalue. Then $(A+B)v=\lambda^{max}_{(A+B)}v=Av+Bv$, and so by the triangle inequality, $|(A+B)v|=\lambda^{max}_{(A+B)}\leq |Av|+|Bv|$. Now, by definition, $|Bv|\leq||B||$. And also, your source mentions that $A$ is diagonal, so its singular values are just the same as (the absolute value of) its eigenvalues, so the magnitude of the largest singular value of $A$ (i.e. $||A||$) should be the same as the magnitude of its largest eigenvalue. Hence $|Av|\leq||A||=\lambda^{max}_A$. So we can conclude $\lambda^{max}_{(A+B)}\leq\lambda^{max}_A+||B||$

Comment: I think your proof is correct. At which point you thought might be not correct? Thanks!